# Error while extracting from result set

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

I am trying to get data from a mysql table. My query returns one value when I run it manually on phpmyadmin but when I run from Java code it gives an empty set. This is the query:

```
SELECT real_name
from doctorlogin
where password='1234' and id='X11111X';
```

Code:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> query(String statement) throws SQLException {
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(statement);
    int numcols = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    if (rs.isBeforeFirst()) {
        do {
            ArrayList<String> row = new ArrayList<String>(); // new list per row
            int i = 0;
            while (i <= numcols) {  // don't skip the last column, use <=
                row.add(rs.getString(i++));
            }
            result.add(row); // add it to the result
        } while (rs.next());
    }

    return result;
}

public String login(String username, String password, String domain) throws SQLException {
    String query = "SELECT real_name from " + domain + "login where password='" + password + "' and id='" + username + "';";
    System.out.println(query);
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> r = query(query);

    if (r.size() > 1 || r.size() == 0)
        return "Login Failed";
    else
        return r.get(0).get(0);
}
```

After making the edit, the code still does not fetch any result even though I get one row in phpmyadmin.

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> query(String statement) throws SQLException {
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(statement);
    int numcols = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    while ( rs.next() ) {
        ArrayList<String> row = new ArrayList<String>(); // new list per row
        for ( int i = 1; i <= numcols; i++ ) {
            row.add(rs.getString(i));
        }
        result.add(row); // add it to the result
    }
    return result;
}
```

Screenshots of query on phpmyadmin -> https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B_yqoCAAV2rFdDZqUzlmeXljNWs

Comment: What is the stracktrace? Did you try to use rs.next() instead of if (rs.isBeforeFirst()) ?

Comment: The code does not even enter the while loop.

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting an SQLException?

Comment: Yeah..It does not give any exception.

Comment: I have added link to screenshots. Can't post photos here because of low reputation.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot retrieve information from the row before calling `rs.next()`. So the usual format of a `ResultSet` loop is simply

```
while (rs.next()) {
    // Retrieve the column values
}
```

There is no need for the `if` statement there. If there are no returned rows, the `if` is false and you'll return an empty list. But the same is true for the simple `while` above. There is no need for `do...while()` - you first need to move the cursor, only then read the values.

Finally, columns are indexed from 1, not from 0. Thus your `i` should start from 1. But why not replace it with a `for` loop instead of a `while`?

```
while ( rs.next() ) {
     ArrayList<String> row = new ArrayList<String>(); // new list per row
     for ( int i = 1; i <= numcols; i++ ) {
         row.add(rs.getString(i));
     }
     result.add(row); // add it to the result
}
```

You should read the [`ResultSet` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) as the information is all there.

Answer (score 0):

```
row.add(rs.getString(i++));
```

should be changed to

```
row.add(rs.getString(++i));
```

Because the row `0` is not accessible. The row count begins at `1`.

In the second code, there's incrementing before getting the object from the DB so the first value is `1`.